# react functional component doesn't render although console shows no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a table which is a monthly calendar that will render an appointment card in the cell if the appointment card id equals the cell id, I am using .filter to filter them by id and then .map to display them in cells(but they didn't render)

the table component renders successfully but the appointment cards don't, and the console shows no errors

here's the table component:

```
import appointments from './appointments'
import OutlinedCard from './card'

const Table = ({columns}) => {       
    const style = {
        border: "1px solid black",
        height: "100vh",
    }

    const appointmentsInthisColumn = appointments.filter(appointment => appointment.id == columns.id);

    return (
        <td style={style}>
            <td>{columns.name}</td>
            {appointmentsInthisColumn.map(appointment => (
                <OutlinedCard appointment={appointment} />
            ))}
        </td>
    )
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Have you checked that `appointmentsInthisColumn` contains elements (that it's not empty)?

Comment: trying to do this now

Comment: it's giving 24 arrays

Comment: Is columns array or an object?

Comment: @maimohamed how do you know it's giving "24 arrays" (I assume you intended to say: an array with 24 elements). Did you add `console.log(appointmentsInthisColumn.length)` after assigning `appointmentsInthisColumn`?

Comment: Another thing that looks suspicious is the `appointment.id == columns.id` comparison within `filter`. Shouldn't this be something like `appointment.columnsId == columns.id`? Or does the `appointment.id` indeed point to the id of a columns? In which case the property name is illogical.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes

Comment: @3limin4t0r an id of a column

Comment: The filtering was the problem but I fixed it and now it works